# Contracting Vertices in graph_tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

I'm trying to switch over from using networkx to graph_tool for python, however there doesn't seem to be a feature in graph_tool to contract nodes. For the purposes of my graph this is also equivalent to [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction). Does anyone know if such a feature exists in graph_tool or how I could implement it? My main concern about implementing it in python is if it slows down considerably such that the switch from networkx to graph_tool may not have been worth it.

Comment: https://archives.skewed.de/hyperkitty/list/graph-tool@skewed.de/thread/VLB3WURFNCP7FCJCH2ZAWQZOR2MU5LJ5/#VLB3WURFNCP7FCJCH2ZAWQZOR2MU5LJ5